# 'no class type' error when trying to resize vector within a structure

Tags: c++, function, vector, data-structures

I'm writing a code with c++ to build a lattice and then calculate the energies between points for running some MD simulations.

I have this working within one continuous main function, but want to split into subroutines so I can change the quantity of cells and only build the lattice for that cell quantity and calculate the desired energies b/w only the intended qty of lattice positions.

The lattice I build uses 3 for loops to write the x, y, and z positions into their respective vectors. I need to pass the three vectors from the 'Lattice' function to the 'energies' function, and figured I would do this using a structure of the 3 vectors.

I've commented out most of the code while trying to get the new structure to work, here's part of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio>
#include <math>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

 //use structure so the x, y, and z vectors can be passed as a return from the lattice function

struct Coordinates{
  vector<double> xValues();
  vector<double> yValues();
  vector<double> zValues(); }; 


//First Function, of type Coordinates
Coordinates makeLattice(int xCell,int yCell,int zCell)  
{
// Initialize a Lattice   

  Coordinates xyz; //creating an object of type:coordinates 'xyz'

  int nCell = xCell*yCell*zCell; //number of cells in system
  int nAtoms = 4*nCell;
  cout<<"number of cells= "<<nCell<<" and number of atoms = " 
  <<nAtoms<<"\n";

  xyz.xValues.resize(nAtoms);
  xyz.yValues.resize(nAtoms);
  xyz.zValues.resize(nAtoms);

  //a whole bunch of commented out code
return xyz;
}
```

I'm getting an error when compiling because "xyz.coordinates::xValues does not have a class type", and the same error for the other two vectors. Can someone tell me what I am missing while using structures?

Comment: I will later want to write the lattice position values into the xyz vectors akin to
xyz.xValues[i] = ax*i

Comment: It would help if you added the exact text of the error message. In Visual Studio its best to copy that from the Output Tab instead of the errors list.

Comment: Delete the `()` in `vector<double> xValues();` (and the others). It thinks you are declaring a function. I believe that is an example of the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Why are you declaring xValues, yValues, zValues in the struct as functions?? Try to remove the `()`, removing `()` will be recognized by the compiler as initialization without parameters.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It's Most Vexing Parse, Junior. Most Vexing Parse adds in an accidental function pointer.

Comment: Well damn, thanks everyone!